# Multiple subdomain using the same virtualhost DocumentRoot (multilanguage website)

Tags: apache, virtualhost, multilingual

For a multilanguage website, I would like (with Virtualhost) to make the subdomain ***fr.mysite.com*** display the content of ***mysite.com***.

Then, with $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], I could fetch subdomain of the url to load the right language file.

Here my Apache conf file :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fr.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to URL *fr.mysite.com*, there is redirection to *www.mysite.com*

What I want is keeping url *fr.mysite.com* but display *www.mysite.com*

Thanks for your help !

Comment: 1) There is no need to have separate VirtualHost, just add another `ServerAlias` 2) The redirect does not come from config you showed us, it is either from `.htaccess` or app itself.

Comment: You are 100% right Dusan. .htaccess file was "hidden" on my main directory. You save me hours.